# Can I use a dynamic DNS server like DynuDNS and use it to host a domain name under something like Namecheap?

Tags: ip-address, dynamic-dns

I'm a bit jumbled up with this dynamic DNS thing and how it works, so say I have a domain name with namecheap (domain.com) and I want to use a dynamic DNS to sync my dynamic IP, would i need to make a hostname with the DDNS provider and have my namecheap domain point to the DDNS hostname which then points to my IP which would be synced automatically? Or does it work in a different way? what would i need to do to host a web server that will sync with my dynamic IP?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your domain provider offers dynamic DNS service, you'll have to go with a CNAME.

Sign up with the dynamic DNS provider of your choice and setup a hostname that will update to your IP as it changes.

Then in your domain providers DNS settings create a CNAME entry for your domain and enter your dynamic dns hostname as the target.

Note that your provider may only allow CNAME for subdomains and not the primary domain.  Meaning you can have `www.example.com` be a CNAME to your dynamic IP but not `example.com`.

Comment: CNAME on the domain root is not allowed by the spec; if DNS providers allow it, they usually fake it by generating real A/AAAA records and just refreshing them every so often. So even if the dynDNS service offers "instant updates", such a pseudo-CNAME [often labelled 'ANAME' or 'ALIAS'] might have an update delay on its own.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a domain with NameCheap, you don't need a third-party provider. Simply switch your domain to use NameCheap's basic DNS services, [download NameCheap's dynamic DNS client](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/111/11/using-namecheap-dynamic-dns-client--version-20x-beta), and create the appropriate dynamic records with NameCheap.

If you wanted to use a dynamic DNS service other than NameCheap, on the NameCheap website you would set your domain to use the custom name servers provided by the dynamic DNS provider (and then use their client to update your IP).